# Why is Hibernate's cache statistics completely different to EhCache's statistics

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, ehcache

I've setup Hibernate to use EhCache for L2 caching of entities. Persistence.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="..." transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    ...
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
            value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I've used the singleton cache provider so that I can get a copy of it in Spring, and expose the EhCache management objects via JMX:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:shared="true" />
<bean id="managementService" class="net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService" 
     init-method="init"
     destroy-method="dispose">
    <constructor-arg ref="cacheManager"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="mbeanServer"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="true"/>
    <constructor-arg index="3" value="true"/>
    <constructor-arg index="4" value="true"/>
    <constructor-arg index="5" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

I'm exposing the Hibernate cache statistics using this method:

```
        MBeanServer mbs = 
                ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        ObjectName mxbeanName = new ObjectName("Project:type=EmfCacheStatistics");
        StatisticsService statisticsService = new StatisticsService();
        statisticsService.setSessionFactory(((HibernateEntityManagerFactory)emf).getSessionFactory());
        statisticsService.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        mbs.registerMBean(statisticsService, mxbeanName);
```

Finally, the ehcache.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false"
monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="1800" overflowToDisk="true"
    diskPersistent="false" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />

</ehcache>
```

Now, when I go an look at the statistics for both systems using JMX I get very different pictures. Note, I reset both sets of statistics and then waited ~30 seconds before taking these screenshots.

In the first screenshot is EhCache. Note the very small ObjectCount. This value fluctuates, but never gets higher than ~20
[image: EhCache statistics]

This is the Hibernate cache statistics. They look about right.
[image: Hibernate cache statistics]

Why do the cache statistics report such wildly different things? It almost looks like the EhCache statistics are not working at all.

I'm using:
 - Hibernate 3.6.10
 - EhCache 2.4.3
 - Spring 3.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same observation with the same error ;)

By default, statistics are disabled on EHCache ; you need to add  **statistics="true"** to your cache definition in ehcache.xml.

Example :

```
<cache name="global" maxElementsInMemory="10" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" statistics="true" />
```